# Добавление jquery в yii2

Tags: jquery, yii2, views

Здравствуйте. Я чет торможу, не могу найти в документации как подключить jquery в Yii2. 
Как понял, можно подключить в файле AppAsset и это будет выглядеть так.

```html
 public $js = ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'];
```

И после этого смогу выполнять функции и методы jquery? 
И что нужно будет подключать в файлах вьюхов, чтобы заработал jquery?
Признателен за ответ. )

Или будет лучше разместить скаченный jquery в директории web?

Comment: На сколько я знаю в yii2 уже по умолчанию используется jquery. ..например у `AppAsset` написана зависимость `public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',];`  у `YiiAsset` написано `public $depends = [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
    ];` ну а в `JqueryAsset` написано `public $js = [
        'jquery.js',
    ];`  )) .... по сути, всё, что нужно, так это нужную версию jquery вписать в конфиг composer скорее всего или какой там сборщик

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В yii2 jquery подключается автоматически, и не нужно ничего писать самому. Проверьте на любой из своих view допустим так

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('jQuery работает');
      });
    </script>
```

Если не сработает, то тогда уже пробуйте подключать через AppAsset

Вот пример моего AppAsset.php

```
<?php

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Никакой вариант не прошел. 
Что без добавления в AppAsset, что с добавлением в AppAsset. 

В AppAsset пробовал добавлять двумя способами. 

 public $js = ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'
    ];
и 
public $js = ['js/jquery-3.2.1.min'
    ];

Comment: Добавил в ответ пример моего файла AppAsset. Проверьте всё ли у Вас правильно?

Comment: Да, так же. 
Проверил, jQuery есть в проекте. 
Сейчас ещё раз пошел по документации, скинули ссылку снизу.

Comment: Нашел в чем ошибка была. ) 
Даже в том, что вы скинули, не хватает одной детали. Подключение самого jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как на счет `AppAsset`, но ты можешь в конфигурационном файле (`config/web.php`) прописать свои пути:

```
$config = [
    ...
    ...

     'components' => [
        'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                    'sourcePath' => null,   // do not publish the bundle
                    'js' => [
                        '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js',
                    ]
                ],                
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

или брать из папки своей

```
'assetManager' => [
    'bundles' => [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
            'sourcePath' => null,
            'basePath' => '@webroot',
            'baseUrl' => '@web',
            'js' => [
                'js/jquery.js',
            ]
        ],
    ],
],
```

Кстати, **[вот гайд на русском](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/structure-assets.md)** и **[вообще инструкции на руссоком](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/tree/master/docs/guide-ru)**

Answer (score 0):

В класс `AppAsset` в атрибут  `public $depends = ['yii\web\JqueryAsset', ];`.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно причина вашей проблемы в том что js подтягивается в конце страницы [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

по причине того что все js собираются в layoute строкой `<?php $this->endBody() ?>`

именно по этой причине вставленный на страницу js работать не будет, его нужно регистрировать примерно следующим образом:

```
<?php
$js = <<< JS
alert("okey!");
JS;

$this->registerJs( $js, $position = yii\web\View::POS_READY, $key = null );
?>
```

и тогда Yii автоматом поместит этот код в конце страницы и все у вас заработает.
Возможно вам поможет вот эта статья: https://coderius.biz.ua/blog/article/yii2-registracia-skriptov-i-stilej-v-view